# How to get ip address of a router?

Tags: wi-fi, router

Normally when a modem/router is connected to a computer, there are multiple ways to know the ip address of them. I am using an android device and, I have free WiFi in my colony.

The problem is that previously the WiFi connected without any issues and the speed was great too. But recently they changed the WiFi frequency from 5 GHz to 2.4 GHz and now the WiFi doesn't get much signal from my home, and hence doesn't connect. And they refused to change it, and the problem is they never understood it, and it was the work of the repairman who changed it.

I am able to connect to the WiFi and it works, when in range, so is there any way to get the ip address of the router so that I can change the frequency. And also the ISP doesn't even respond to calls, and comes in months if there is any problem. And also I know the password and username, so don't respond to it that I am hacking something.

And when I connect to the WiFi it assigns me 192.168.43.214 address. So please tell me is there any way to know the ip address of the router.

Comment: try installing the app [Network Info II](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.networkInfoIi&hl=en). The router IP-Address is listed under "Default Gateway". Using the terminal might be possible to (ifconfig wlan0) but I think it requires root so just try the app

Comment: Given your IP address, try 192.168.43.0 and 192.168.43.1.

Comment: @mattm `.0` is unlikely, `.1` a good guess without guarantee. Using a terminal app (or `adb shell`), the command `route` would give a definite answer – as the router will be the point the device routes to. So any `192.168.43.X` address showing up as gateway (`gw`) in the `route` output will be the router.

Comment: The Gateway should be the IP address of the router here which you can get from multiple ways. If benjamin's comment doesn't help then try [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) -> Information -> Wifi -> More information to see the Gateway's IP address. Alternatively, you can use [tag:adb] to query Wifi service. Do `adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep Gateway`. It is another matter that the log in page for router could be set at a different IP address.

Comment: @Izzy, what specific parameter does `route` needs to get the information relevant to question? It's simply giving me error "Invalid argument".  Works well on desktop though.

Comment: @Firelord that confuses me – I had expected "no argument", like the desktop variant. Right, "invalid argument". What worked: `busybox route` outputs the routing information as expected – no idea what AOSP (or Google) compiled for the native `route` command – whatever option I provided (`-n|-v|-F|-C|-A`) only provoked an "applet not found" error. Sorry for that, I should have tested it before.

Comment: Nothing works, the router is blocking access to 192.168.43.1 and is unreachable to others. What can I do?

Comment: I know that cSploit shows the gateway IP for sure, however I'm not sure if you'll get to see it without root.